# Problem when stacking overloaded operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I need to make a vector class and when I'm trying to use overloaded operators, it fails to compile with an error:

```
error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Vector' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
message : could be 'char Vector::operator =(std::initializer_list<double>)'
message : or       'char Vector::operator =(double *)'
message : or       'char Vector::operator =(Vector &)'
message : while trying to match the argument list '(Vector, Vector)'
```

when I'm trying to following operation in main:

```
#include "vector.h"

int main(void)
{
Vector x {1., 2., 3., 4.};
Vector y(4);

y = -x; 

return 0;
}
```

I can't pass return value in operator- as reference because it goes out of scope.
When I change operator= to `char operator=(Vector V);`  it does not work either and throws memory leak exception.
Is it possible to make that work in C++?

my class:

```
#ifndef _VECTOR_H
#define _VECTOR_H

#include <initializer_list>

class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(unsigned int _N);
    Vector(std::initializer_list<double> values);
    Vector(Vector& copy);
    ~Vector(void);

    double& operator[](int i) { return vec[i]; }
    Vector& operator=(Vector& copy);
    Vector operator-(void);

    unsigned int size(void) { return N; }

private:
    unsigned int N{ 0 };
    double* vec{ nullptr };
};

void disp(Vector& vec);

#endif
```

and methods:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include "vector.h"

Vector::Vector(unsigned int _N) :
    N(_N)
{
    vec = new double[N];
    if (vec == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("Memory allocation faliure. ");
}

Vector::Vector(std::initializer_list<double> values) :
    Vector(values.size())
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        vec[i] = values.begin()[i];
}

Vector::Vector(Vector& copy) :
    Vector(copy.size())
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        vec[i] = copy[i];
}

Vector::~Vector()
{
    delete[] vec;
}

Vector& Vector::operator=(Vector& copy)
{
    if (this != &copy)
    {
        if (N != copy.size())
        {
            delete[] vec;
            N = copy.size();
            vec = new double[N];
            if (vec == nullptr)
                throw std::runtime_error("Memory allocation faliure. ");
        }
        
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            vec[i] = copy[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

Vector Vector::operator-(void)
{
    Vector ret(N);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        ret[i] = -vec[i];

    return ret;
}

void disp(Vector& vec)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        std::cout << vec[i] << '\t';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it meets all requirements of a [mre], as explained in the help center. The issue seems obvious to me; however due to a lack of a [mre] it is not possible to simply cut/paste the shown code ***exactly as shown*** and verify that fixing the obvious problem will actually fix the compilation error.

Comment: `vec = (double*)malloc(N * sizeof(double));` -- Why are you using `malloc` instead of `new[]`.  On the same point, why are you not simply using `std::vector<double>` and create a class wrapper around that type?

Comment: First of all, all assignment operators should return a reference to its own object. Secondly, `Vector::operator =(Vector &)` should be `Vector::operator =(const Vector &)`

Comment: Also, `operator=` in your case should mean what it says -- you are assigning an existing object to another existing object of the same type.  The programmer is expecting `Vector x; Vector y; x = y;` to mean that whatever `x` was, now make it the same as `y`, no different than `int x = 1; int y = 0; x = y;` would make `x` equal to `0`.  Otherwise, the class is confusing and can cause hard-to-find bugs.  The assignment operator should be analogous to the copy constructor, and in your case, it is not.

Comment: `int main() { Vector v1(1); Vector v2(4); v1 = v2; }` that small program is expected to have `v1` with 4 elements at the end, with no memory leaks, double free's, or memory corruption when `main` returns.  Once you can get passed that threshold, then the class would somewhat be usable and then you can focus on operator overloading.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  I've tried previously `int main(void) {  Vector x { 1., 2., 3., 4. };  Vector y{ 2. , 3. , 5., 7. };  y = x;  return 0  }` and it works as intended.

Comment: Now make `x` have a different number of elements than `y`.  It no longer works.  Your assignment operator does radically different things than the copy constructor.  In other words `Vector x(4); Vector y(10); x = y;`.  What happens there?

Comment: This program is an assignment for my class and it should be written in C. I asked my teacher if I can add some C++ to learn something new and I can but I can't use containers. Also i'm more use to C so I'm using 'malloc' for now.

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages.  If the goal is to write C++, then you should be writing C++, not mixing in C code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie When I try 'Vector x(4); Vector y(10); x = y;' the = operator returns 1 and nothing happens. I wrote it that way so there is no memory leak.

Comment: I edited my code so now it uses `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @los0220 -- You are missing the point.  The assignment operator and copy constructor are expected to do the same thing.  Your case, it doesn't.  You are purposefully returning if the sizes are different -- *it is not supposed to do that*.  The assignment operator shouldn't care what the size is -- it should throw away the old data, and assign what is passed in.  That is what I mean by it being analogous to the copy constructor.

Comment: I'll make it easy for you:  `Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& V) { Vector temp(V); std::swap(temp.N, N); std::swap(temp.vec, vec); return *this; }` -- That does what I am trying to explain.

Comment: Ok, I replaced my assignment operator with something I came up with. I think it does what you said and now I'll try to analise what you wrote. Is this some thing that is required for code to work or is it a good practice? However that still does not fix my issue.

Comment: Solution to my issue turned out to be using const Vector in operator overload: `Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& copy)` with `double& operator[](int i) const { return vec[i]; }` and `unsigned int size(void) const { return N; }`. Thank you very mutch for your help and sorry for my long response times and lack of understanding.